# Use of comma in a sentence where there are mutiple nouns and verbs

Tags: commas

I find it interesting to add comma into this sentence, but I do not know how to make it right.

The first one: Shely likes to eat cakes, apples, and wear red skirts, green hats, and white jeans.
The second one: Shely likes to eat cakes and apples and wear red skirts, green hats, and white jeans.

So, which would you think it more appropriate?

Comment: Prefer the second  (although many people would omit the Oxford comma) https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/

Comment: @RonaldSole I feel there's a subtle difference between "green hats, and white jeans" and "green hats and white jeans". The second implies she likes to wear all 3 things at once (multiple skirts, multiple hats and the jeans) whereas the first separates them a little bit more, so as to suggest that these are the things she likes, singly.

Comment: @PrimeMover I wouldn't argue with that.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. This is better than both:

"Shely likes to eat cakes and apples, and wear red skirts, green hats, and white jeans."

It is important to separate the two thoughts: things she likes to eat (cakes and apples) and things she likes to wear (the other stuff).

Comment: I think this is good, but until now I have not found a grammar book write about it.